# Spring Web Client Not Binding JSON to POJO correctly?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-webflux, jackson-databind

Hi I'm using Spring Web Client to access [Taste Dive REST API](https://tastedive.com/read/api).

Here's the method I use to access the endpoint

```
public TasteDiveItemDto getReccs(Collection<Book> bookCollection) {

    String parameters = ""; 

    for(Book b : bookCollection)
        parameters = parameters + "book:" + b.getTitle() + "%2C";

    // remove the %2C at end of string 
    parameters = parameters.substring(0, parameters.length() - 3);

    logger.info("Parameters = " + parameters);

    // We want 2 reccs for every 1 book in the collection 
    int limit = bookCollection.size() * 2; 

    String req = "/similar" + "?q=" + parameters + "&" + "k=" + API_KEY + "&" + "limit=" + Integer.toString(limit);

    logger.info("req = " + req);

    logger.info("Accessing TasteDive API...");

    return CLIENT.get().uri(req).retrieve().bodyToMono(TasteDiveItemDto.class).block(); 
}
```

And here are my POJOs

```
public class TasteDiveItemDto {
@JsonProperty("Similar")
private Similar similar;

public Similar getSimilar() {
    return similar;
}

public void setSimilar(Similar similar) {
    this.similar = similar;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TasteDiveItemDto [similar=" + similar + "]";
}
}
```

---

```
public class Similar {

@JsonProperty("Info")
private Info[] info;

@JsonProperty("Results")
private Info[] results;

public Info[] getInfo() {
    return info;
}

public void setInfo(Info[] info) {
    this.info = info;
}

public Info[] getResults() {
    return results;
}

public void setResults(Info[] results) {
    this.results = results;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Similar [info=" + Arrays.toString(info) + ", results=" + Arrays.toString(results) + "]";
}
}
```

---

```
public class Info {

@JsonProperty("Name")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("Type")
private String type;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Info [name=" + name + ", type=" + type + "]";
}
 }
```

Here's what I'm getting back from the endpoint when I use my toString method

```
TasteDiveItemDto 
[
similar=
    Similar 
    [
        info=
        [
            Info 
            [
                name=book:chemistry%2cbook:norwegian wood%2cbook:infinite jest%2cbook:flowers for algernon, 
                type=unknown
            ], 

            Info 
            [
                name=book:chemistry%2cbook:norwegian wood%2cbook:infinite jest%2cbook:flowers for algernon, 
                type=unknown
            ]
        ], 

            results=[]
    ]   
 ]
```

So what's essentially getting mapped are the parameters I put in the endpoint and not the correct JSON response. I've tried to use @JsonProperty on the methods and fields but to no luck.

I'm still a beginner at Spring and only read a bit of the Web Client documentation so I can't figure out entirely what I'm doing incorrectly. The strange thing is when I used Web Client to access Google Books API using the same methodology it worked out perfectly.

Please let me know if you need anymore information from my program. Thanks!

Comment: in java we don't concatenate strings to build urls, the only language you do that is in php (i think) . You can instead use the `queryparam` function to build your request https://www.baeldung.com/webflux-webclient-parameters#single-value-parameters

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thank you! That seemed to have worked! I used URI from java's net library to construct a quick test and my POJOs are now populated with the correct response. I'm going to do it properly with queryparam now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Concatenating strings in urls and sql are a security risk and is biggest reason for so called ”sql injections”. Try to always avoid it if you can.